# How to convert g729 encoded byte array to .wav pcm_alaw in Java?

Tags: java, audio, codec, format-conversion, g729

I have voice part from RTP payload in byte array. It's encoded in g729 codec. How to convert g729 encoded byte array to .wav pcm_alaw in Java code? Anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do g729 decode. Decoding will give you PCM samples. 
You can search for open source decoders, I saw that people use open G.729 decoder and ffmpeg (libavcodec).